# Bootstrap Widgets tblistview: How not to show total itemcount?

Tags: php, activerecord, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to modify a table built using Yii boostrap and CactiveDataprovider, the table works fine but it automatically also displays the count of all items found, how to disable displaying this count 
 
this is the view logic currently

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'viewData'=>array('page'=>$page),
    'itemsTagName'=>'table',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'items table table-striped table-condensed',
    'emptyText'=>'<i> Sorry, there are no active items to display</i>',
                  ));
```

Comment: are you reffering to something like this: http://screencast.com/t/QkYjqIDX ?

Comment: yes i am referring to the same, in some use cases that data is not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line:

```
'template' => "{sorter}\n{items}\n{pager}",
```

TbListView extends from CListView, which uses the template variable to control the layout. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail

The default template is `"{summary}\n{sorter}\n{items}\n{pager}"` where {summary} is what shows the count. So if you remove that, the count won't show

Comment: thanks it worked :) .. with your method i was also able to move the summary content to the footer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might be reffering to: [example](http://screencast.com/t/QkYjqIDX)

If so, set the template property as needed.

You need to delete the `summary` text.

`pages` stands for the pagination

`items` stands for ... the list of items

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'template' => "{summary}\n{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}\n{pager}",
    'itemView' => '_index',
    'pager' => array(
        'maxButtonCount' => 10,
    ),
        )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy.
 put propriety summaryText false.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view_mercado',
    'summaryText'=>false //make it for hide summary text
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this alternative answer from an offline source, posting here for completeness.
Both Ionut-flavius-Pogacian and frostyterrier methods worked and are better solutions as defining the template gives even more control over the widget behavior rather than just defining the summaryText as in the answer below

Tblistview is not documented in Yii-bootstrap documentation, but scanning the source it seems it is wrapper for CListview class in Yii.

CListview extends CBaseListView which has the summaryText property. Passing Blank data to it, removes the count which is active by default.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#template-detail

SummaryText has the following usable variables

```
{start}: the starting row number (1-based) currently being displayed 
{end}: the ending row number (1-based) currently being displayed 
{count}: the total number of rows
{page}: the page number (1-based) current being displayed, available since version 1.1.3
{pages}: the total number of pages, available since version 1.1.3 

{start} {end} and {count} are visible by default
```

The code could be modified to

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'viewData'=>array('page'=>$page),
    'itemsTagName'=>'table',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'items table table-striped table-condensed',
    'emptyText'=>'<i> Sorry, there are no active items to display</i>',
    'summaryText'=>''
                  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using CSS? is pretty straight forward

Comment: How would you to that ? do you mean by hiding the specific class ?

Comment: the way i did it was
        .list-view 
            .summary {
                display:none;
            }
use a container to make sure it only hides in the place you want it and not across all the app

Comment: That should have work for me i guess, but isn't it a bit messy? is not better to change at the php/framework side of things rather than hiding it by CSS ?? I mean why pass data to the view if it is not going to be used at all?

Comment: I know, unfortunately the docs are not very clear about all the things you can do and many hacks are necessary, plus, is just a couple bites more or so, it won't affect your performance.

Comment: Yeah, true the documentation is not quite comprehensive, and extensions are even worse :(

Comment: is so frustrating, i'm bought a template at wrapbootstrap.com and to implementing i've had to change a lot of widgets to generate the html i need

Comment: yeah.. wrapbootstrap is really a rip off, the templates have zero documentation. What is the point in paying for something if you are getting no extra value from someone who is just using a site grabber to do pirate the template??